# Используя SimpleXml недоступны некоторые поля

Tags: rss, simplexml

С помощью SimpleXml читаю кусок ленты

```
<item>
   <title>The Justices Lay Down the Law</title><pubDate>Wed, 28 Jun 2017 14:07:05 -0500</pubDate>
   <fullpubdate>06/28/2017/00/00/00</fullpubdate>
   <description><![CDATA[ <a href="/authors/david_rivkin" data-mce-href="../../authors/david_rivkin">Rivkin</a> &amp; <a href="/authors/lee_casey" data-mce-href="../../authors/lee_casey">Casey</a>, <span class="source">Wall Street Journal</span><br />In the travel-ban case, a high-court &lsquo;compromise&rsquo; delivers a unanimous rebuke to political judges.]]></description><link>https://www.realclearpolitics.com/2017/06/28/the_justices_lay_down_the_law_414173.html</link><originalLink>https://t.co/y0BkZIKyc1</originalLink> <guid isPermaLink="false">100414173</guid>
 <category>PM Update</category> 
 <author><![CDATA[ <a href="/authors/david_rivkin" data-mce-href="../../authors/david_rivkin">Rivkin</a> &amp; <a href="/authors/lee_casey" data-mce-href="../../authors/lee_casey">Casey</a>, Wall Street Journal]]></author><media:content url="https://assets.realclear.com/images/41/419326_1_.jpg" type="image/jpeg" height="190" width="250" />
   <media:thumbnail url="https://assets.realclear.com/images/41/419326_3_.jpg" height="60" width="90" />
   <media:title>The Justices Lay Down the Law</media:title>
   </item>

$content_data = @file_get_contents($this->data_source);
$xmlDataArray = new \SimpleXmlElement($content_data);
foreach($xmlDataArray->channel->item as $nextXmlRow) {
    dump($nextXmlRow);
    dump($nextXmlRow->media);

    dump($nextXmlRow->author);
```

И я получаю вывод :

```
SimpleXMLElement {#368 ▼
  +"title": "The Justices Lay Down the Law"
  +"pubDate": "Wed, 28 Jun 2017 14:07:05 -0500"
  +"fullpubdate": "06/28/2017/00/00/00"
  +"description": SimpleXMLElement {#373}
  +"link": "https://www.realclearpolitics.com/2017/06/28/the_justices_lay_down_the_law_414173.html"
  +"originalLink": "https://t.co/y0BkZIKyc1"
  +"guid": "100414173"
  +"category": "PM Update"
  +"author": SimpleXMLElement {#374}
}
SimpleXMLElement {#370}
SimpleXMLElement {#370 ▼
  +0: SimpleXMLElement {#377}
}
```

Узлы media и author пусты, хотя в исходном коде видно что они имею значение...
Как получить значение этих полей? Есть что-то лучше SimpleXml ?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте SimpleXml. Только обратите внимание на namespace media:.

```
$content_data = @file_get_contents("text.xml");
$_ = simplexml_load_string($content_data);
foreach($_->item as $nextXmlRow) {
    var_export((string)$nextXmlRow->author);
    var_export($nextXmlRow->children('media', true));
}
```

HTML код:

```
<a href="/authors/david_rivkin" data-mce-href="../../authors/david_rivkin">Rivkin</a> &amp; <a href="/authors/lee_casey" data-mce-href="../../authors/lee_casey">Casey</a>, Wall Street Journal'
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
'content' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
  )),
   'thumbnail' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
  )),
   'title' => 'The Justices Lay Down the Law',
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Повторюсь. media это пространство имен. Содержимое этого пространства (ноды) получаем `$nextXmlRow->children('media', true)`. Атрибуты нодов доступны через метод `attributes()`. Для получения строкового значения используем приведение к типам (string). В документации к SimpleXml все подробно расписано.